# Do most most neural net weight optimization algorithms use final weights or best weights?

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, optimization

Say I'm training neural net in a framework such as tensorflow or caffe. Tensorflow keeps track of the loss of that model as it trains, and then saves off a model at the end. I'm wondering if it is common practice to save the weights that had the lowest loss during training, or to simply save the weights that exist at the end of training. If the lowest loss weights aren't saved, why? Wouldn't those be the ideal weights to keep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you keep track of the validation error during training. Then you always keep the parameters around that were minimal on that, and use that at the end. You also don't train much longer after the validation error has started to rise. this is called "early stopping".

However, there is an issue with it, which are mostly practical. For one, you will have lower validation error for 90% of the training. If you always copy the parameters then, you will spend lots of time copying. If that involves a GPU-CPU transfer, you need to spend quite some time fiddling until you find a satisfactory trade off between training time and frequency of keeping the best parameters around. This is especially the case for large data settings, where you don't overfit a lot anyway, and your final parameters and the best parameters won't make much of a difference.